# The order of an element in quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have to solve the following problem:

> We've got a group: $G =\mathbb Z_{36} \times \mathbb Z_{60}$. 
>   And a subgroup of $G$ called $H = \left< ( 5+36\mathbb Z , 10+60\mathbb Z ) \right>$.
>   The operation is : $+$ 
>   Which is the order of the element $\overline{(4,2)}$ in the group $G/H$ ?

If I'm not wrong, the order of the group G/H, which is written as |G/H|, is equal to |G|/|H| when G is finite (and in this case, I think that |G|=|G1 x G2|=|G1|x|G2|=36*60=2160). But I don't know if this is okay because I think this number is quite big. 
Anyway, how can I calculate the order of an element in G/H; in this case the order of the element (4,2) in the group G/H? (*above the 4 and 2 there is a line)?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the order of an element $g$ in a multiplicative group as the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=1$.

If the group is a quotient group, say $G/H$, the order is computed the same, but, since $gH=1H$ if and only if $g\in H$, the problem becomes to find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k\in H$.

With additive notation it's the same, just substitute multiples. Therefore you need to find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that
$$
k(4+36\mathbb{Z},2+60\mathbb{Z})\in H
$$
Now use the definition of $H$.

Comment: I've tried again with the information you have written but I don't know how I can find k and I don't understand the exercise in its whole.

Comment: Would you be able to explain it more extensively, please?

Comment: @Maialen You need to write $k(4+36\mathbb{Z},2+60\mathbb{Z})=t(5+36\mathbb{Z},10+60\mathbb{Z})$, for some integer $t$, with $k>0$ as small as possible. So $4k\equiv 5t\pmod{36}$ and $2k\equiv10t\pmod{60}$.